# Exim is ignoring my ACL definitions for blacklists

Tags: acl, exim

As I am running several free sites which are CMS - based spammers are massivly attacking me. So I decided to set up my exim4 - installation for blacklisting domains.
Exim seems not to care about any restrictions I builded in:

```
acl_check_host:
    accept
            hosts = +local_domains

    deny
            log_message = blacklisted 
            hosts = blacklisted.com

    accept
acl_check_data:
   deny senders = someone@blacklisted.com
   accept

acl_check_sender:
  deny    domains       =  +rbl_blacklist
  deny    senders       = someone@blacklisted.com
```

I haven't got a clue.

```
Exim version 4.80.1 #21 built 04-Feb-2013 16:14:51


Support for: crypteq iconv() OpenSSL Content_Scanning DKIM Old_Demime
Lookups (built-in): lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch dbm dbmjz dbmnz dnsdb    mysql
Authenticators: cram_md5 plaintext
Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
Transports: appendfile/maildir/mailstore/mbx autoreply pipe smtp
Fixed never_users: 0
Size of off_t: 8
Configuration file is /etc/exim/exim.conf
```

Comment: Are you sure that you receive spam messages via remote SMTP and not via some local web-to-mail gateway (CMS comments form or something like this)? Line from log or Received: header from spam mail will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that are mails targeted at registering to the portals. Also exim -v ... succeeds for blacklisted domains.